# What's wrong with this syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select count(*),snum from enrolled group by snum where count(*)=(select count(distinct(cname)) from enrolled;);
```

I am using MYSQL 5.7

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aggregation functions in a `where` clause.  You want a `having` clause:

```
select count(*), snum
from enrolled
group by snum 
having count(*) = (select count(distinct cname ) from enrolled);
```

In addition, only one semi-colon can appear, at the end of the query.  And, although this is not a syntax error, `distinct` is not a function, so it doesn't require parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an aggregate term in a `where` clause. Instead, you should use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*), snum
FROM     enrolled
GROUP BY snum
HAVING   COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT(cname))
```